# saving hardware information before giving it for servicing

Tags: hardware-detection

Let's say I am going for a RAM upgrade. My laptop is brand new and is in fully working condition. Before I give my laptop to the technician, I want to ensure that that he does not change working parts.

What information should I save before I provide my laptop for service? How can I find out what parts were changed and crosscheck that working parts were not removed/replaced.

Comment: mark the components with a custom colored paint.

Comment: Use your favorite hardware information/inventory tool (e.g. Speccy or similar) and note as much information as you want. Getting the serial number of parts is probably the easiest. @IporSircer depending on the part that is a very bad idea as a lot of "paint" is conductive.

Comment: the most hardware parts doesn't have any serial number.

Comment: In addition to Seth's comment, it could be a good idea to print the list and get signature of the technician before giving it to him. Otherwise it'll be very difficult to prove that part was changed by him.

Comment: If you don’t trust the guy to not steal bits, why are you trusting him to fix it? I’d find it offensive if someone asked me to sign a comprehensive parts list before starting a repair - it would make me want to run a similar list in the customer’s presence & check they agreed, before accepting the device.

Comment: @Tetsujin My laptop has warranty and if I need to retain it, I need to take my laptop to a authorized service center. If I take it to someone else, I'll lose my warranty. There is just one authorized center in my city; hence, I have no options.

Comment: Well.. expect him to show the same level of trust. He has no proof your list is correct unless he runs the same test.